# Regular Expression in R: extract characters and numbers from a column

Tags: regex, r

I am working with a retail dataset which has a size description column. My task is to clean the column and separate the numeric size from the characters in the string. Is there a way to do it through regular expressions? I need to save both the number and any other character string present in the column in two different columns.

Observations about the data:

- The column contains sizes of three broad categories: footwear, topwear and bottom wear.
- Footwear: the number in the cell is generally the size and anything other than that is to be stored separately. The unique cases look like - EU 36 ( EU says its European size so conversion is required), UK 8(similar conversion required), 19 Wide, 10 Kids, 19(-25F)( in this case, I really do not need to save -25F info).
- Topwear: The sizes here are generally XXS,XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,XXXL. Any other string along with it, like Tall, inseam etc. needs to be stored seperately. Also a size like XXL can also be represented as 2XL.
- Bottomwear: Size here generally occurs at the beginning. It can be a number- 32 or a character- XL(similar to topwear). If there is any other character string following it, it should be stored separately.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show more of the data? Using `regular expression` requires coming up with a pattern and just one line of text is not enough to create a consistent pattern.

Comment: Yes, show at least three lines of input, say, and also show how the output that corresponds to the input should look.  Also show the code for any attempts you have made.

Comment: You also need to specify to us (if not to yourself already) whether the "F" , inches-double-quote and degree sign need to be recognized without regard to order in the line of data.

Comment: Edited according to comments received, let me know if anything else is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex for those multiple cases.
It works for the examples.

```
details <- c("EU 36", "UK 8", "19 Wide", "10 Kids", "19(-25F)", "XXS", "XS is Extra Small", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL", "XXXL", "2XL", "32")

pattern = "\\b(?:(?:(?:2?X*(?:S|L))|M|(?:EU|UK) [0-9]+)|(?:[0-9]{2}(?: (?:Kids|Wide))?))\\b"

matches <- regexpr(pattern, details)

regmatches(details, matches)
```

Breakdown of the regex:

```
\b    # Word boundary: a position between a word and non-word character 
      # (includes the start/end of the line).
  (?:       # a non-capturing group
    (?:     # ditto
      (?:   # ditto
         2?  # 0 or 1 "2" characters
           X*  # 0 or more "X" characters
             (?:S|L) # "S" or an "L" character
      )
      |    # or
       M   # the "M" character
      |    # or 
       (?:EU|UK) [0-9]+  # "EU" or "UK", followed by a space and 1 or more digits
      |    # or
       (?:[0-9]{2}(?: (?:Kids|Wide))? # 2 digits optionally followed by " Kids" or " Wide"
    )
  )
\b  # Word boundary
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot @LukStroms, this is vey helpful. Can you please elaborate on how to understand this regular expression? I am sorry but I am pretty new to using these for texual analysis.

Comment: Added an elaboration on the regex used in the answer.  [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) exist already since before the existance of the internet. So finding  documentation or even a [online tester](https://regex101.com/) is easy.